# Environment variable $QUERY_STRING is not being included with *envp[]

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, environment-variables, getenv

I have set an environment variable with the following command:

```
QUERY_STRING='This is my query string'
```

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
      printf("%s\n", getenv("QUERY_STRING"));
}
```

And this is what I get when I run the program:

```
mantis@toboggan /testing/cgi_download/temp $ echo $QUERY_STRING; ./a.out
This is my query string.
Segmentation fault
mantis@toboggan /testing/cgi_download/temp $
```

It appears as though the environment variable is not being set, and so `getenv()` is returning a `NULL`.

I really don't know why this isn't working.  Other variables like $PATH are available.  How do I set this environment variable so that it's available to my program?

uname -a:

```
Linux toboggan 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Note that `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @ace:  Not when you're reducing your code to only contain the error!  But I understand where you're coming from. ;)

Comment: False. The C standard specifies that `main` should return `int`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/3488231

Comment: @ace:  If I change it to `int main` from `void main` then my program would require another line of code, and thus wouldn't be reduced to only show the error.

Comment: Have you `export` ed it?  For an environment variable to be available to subprocesses, you have to export it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shell command:

```
QUERY_STRING='This is my query string'
```

creates a shell variable, not an environment variable. Shell variables are local to the shell process, not passed on to child processes like your `a.out`. To make it an environment variable, you need to export it:

```
export QUERY_STRING
```

Comment: By the way, I have not been able to reproduce your problem... When I don't export the variable it `SIGSEGV` *but no printing at all*.  If I export the variable, it works fine.  But I have never got both answers together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the variable so that it propagates into the child processes:

```
 export QUERY_STRING='This is my query string'
```